# Batch copy text to an echo

Tags: batch-file, text, web, copy, echo

So I plan to make a little file downloader in batch and I want to display something like the latest version number. I would like to create a .txt file with something like v1.2 etc and then when you run the batch script, it uses the "echo" command and echoes exactly what it says in the text file. I've tried googling this but no luck. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: `set /P version=< file.txt` `echo %version%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this in your batch file:

```
@echo off
pushd "%~dp0"
type "version.txt"
```

This will echo out the contents of version.txt, which is on the same direction of the normal Batch file.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Worked perfectly.

Comment: @Chearful: But you asked for a different thing: "it uses the "echo" command..."! I suggest you to edit the description or at least change the topic title to something like "Batch display a text file". If `type "file.txt"` is the solution to your problem, then the rep points should go to MC ND (just my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go more complex with a save feature telling the program what happened and stuff, do this to save:

```
(
  echo %Version%
  echo %log%
) > Save.prgmsav
```

That saves the version and log variable, this is how you load them:

```
< Save.prgmsav (
  set /p Version=
  set /p log=
)
```

The .prgmsav can be .txt too. The save name can be a variable, as well.